# Max length of query string in an AJAX GET request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there/what is the maximum length of the query string when doing an AJAX GET request? More specifically, I am doing cross-domain AJAX using an image:

```
img = new Image();
img.src = "http://www.otherdomain.com/something.gif?long_query_string=long........";
```

What is the limit on the query string here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no defined limit in any specification. The **effective** or prescribed limit is 2048 characters. Certain browsers and Webserver will have problems with longer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Query Strings have a maximum length, IIRC it's 2048 chars, or something similar. Though specific implementations probably differ.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Compatibility_issues) has a little bit of info.

Answer (score 0):

Max length for a GET is 2,048 characters =]